# Run image in docker

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and i watched many videos and also studied articles. From there i came to know what exactly docker is.
But my question is -:

Lets suppose i have three docker image

1. First image of "Application 1" is created in window 7/8/10 environment
2. Second image of "Application 2" is  created in CentOs .
3. Third docker of "Application 3"  image is create in Linux.

so , can i run all these three images simultaneously in single environment(Window or CentOS or Linux)  ?

Comment: yes, because they only use the linux kernel of the host (running inside a vm in windows). The images/containers are the same on all platform and behave in the same way

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can ! That's the advantage of docker . Docker runs images on any platform without worrying that what is inside image. So on centos you can run a ubuntu image and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any Linux Docker container image created recently on any Docker host running Linux. There are exceptions around various kernel features which you might not have access to on an older kernel, though, for example. Windows apps do not run on Docker on Linux unless you are doing something like running them under Wine.

Answer (score 0):

There is Windows specific containers which only runs on windows hosts, but if you are using the standard (none-windows-exclusive) images, they run the same on all hosts.

One of the core ideas with docker is that you should be able to run your  service in the exact same environment (the container) on any system (the host). Which works pretty well (with the exception of the windows specific containers!).